# Как писать на Spring 4 + Hibernate 4?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Делаю проект учебных целях на spring + hibernate. По примерам написал часть функционала, но в зависимостях указал Spring 4.1.5 и hibernate 4. Возникли ошибки с созданием бинов.

Затем узнал, что могут быть проблемы с совместимостью версий и заменил версии на spring 3.0.5 и hibernate 3.3.0. Но эти версии работают на java 7, но сейчас все перешли на 8 и 9? (Я могу быть не прав, исправьте). Да и проект на таких версиях тоже не запускается (Остаётся одна ошибка, решается откатом на java 7).

Отсюда возник вопрос: Как писать на spring + hibernate в наши дни? Какие версии этих фреймворков совместимы? Я никак не могу найти хорошую статью с примером правильного создания Контекста и Бинов на этой связке. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: У меня была подобная проблема. Решение в таких случаях находят скопировав в поисковик сообщение об ошибке. Результат поиска должен привести в соответствующую тему на StackOverflow, потому что вы не первый кто столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Comment: @НиколайБеляков, Я так и делал :) Как раз это помогло решить ошибки создания бинов, но привело к ошибке, которая решается откатом на java 7, но меня интересует совместимость под 8 Java (9 даже не будем трогать)

Comment: У меня проекты на Spring 4 и Hibernate 4 прекрасно компилируются и выполняются в Java 9. Проблема у вас в чём-то другом.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, Вероятно, проблема в поднятии контекста (если я верно выражаюсь). Дело в том, что проект я делал по примеру с третьего спринга, там настройки в xml файлах. Но где-то я читал, что сейчас от этого уходят, возможно в этом проблема. Конкретно xml есть у меня на [гитхабе](https://github.com/alexx-stepan/BookLibrary/tree/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring)

Comment: В чём конкретно проблема можно определить только по стектрейсу ошибки. Проблем с использованием xml-конфигураций на сегодняшний день нет.